# What is the suitable db for bulk writes

Tags: google-app-engine

My application is currently on app engine server. My application writes the records(for logging and reporting) continuously.

Scenario: Views count in the website. When we open the website it hits the server to add the  record with time and type of view. Showing these counts in the users dashboard.

Seems these requests are huge now. For now 40/sec. Google App Engine writes are going heavy and cost is increasing like anything.

Is there any way to reduce this or any other db to log the views?

Comment: Post relevant code and fix spelling in title.

Comment: @ZigMandel This question does not need relevant code. kunal answer is ok

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine's Datastore is NOT suitable for such a requirement where you have to continuously write to datastore and read less often.

You need to offload this task to a third party service (either you write one or use existing one)

Better option for user tracking and analytics is Google Analytics (Although you wont be directly able to show the hit counters on website using analytics).

If you want to show your user page hit count use a page hit counter: https://www.google.com/search?q=hit+counter

Comment: It IS possible to retrieve counters crom analytics.

Comment: Thanks Kunal. It is ok. But is there any other thing we can do from our end ? Can we get any betterment if we use google cloud storage/google sql databases ?

Comment: @ZigMandel yes it MAY be with the API but the OP needs a stats counter like functionality. I don't think Google Analytics is right choice for displaying hit counters on website.

Comment: @Govind Google Cloud SQL will likely be better than DataStore but surely not the most optimal way. You might have deal with transactions and moreover aggregate queries will eventually become slower for large dataset. I would still suggest offloading the task to a dedicated service just for showing hit counters.

Comment: If you are just adding a number to a single sql row, the table never actually grows, so it wont slow down because there is no large dataset.

Comment: I don't think that would help in 40 req/sec scenario updating same row with updated count. Transactions (locks) would slow the whole system down.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should avoid Datastore.

For this kind of analytics it's best to do the following:

1. Dump data to GAE log (yes, this sounds counter-intuitive, but it's actually advice from google engineers). GAE log is persistent and is guaranteed to not loose data you write to it.
2. Periodically parse the log for your data and then export it to BigQuery.
3. BigQuery has a quite powerful query language so it's capable of doing complex analytics reports.

Luckily this was already done before: see the [Mache framework](https://github.com/StreakYC/mache). Also see [related video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTyMirxB-RY).

Note: there is now a new [BigQuery feature called streaming inserts](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2013/09/google-bigquery-goes-real-time-with-streaming-inserts-time-based-queries-and-more.html), which could potentially replace the cumbersome middle step (files on Cloud Storage) used in Mache.